# UNIQUE constraint on DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, constraints

Can I have a clustered key on `DataTable` in C# ?

There's a requirement in my code to have constraints for possible combinations of 3 columns to be unique .....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is really a **unique constraint** on your `DataTable`. *Clustered keys* are a SQL Server on-disk feature and not applicable to a `DataTable`.

Check out [MSDN doc on DataTable constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1t2c35.aspx):

> *The UniqueConstraint object, which can be assigned either to a single column or to an array of columns in a DataTable, ensures that all data in the specified column or columns is unique per row. You can create a unique constraint for a column or **array of columns** by using the UniqueConstraint constructor.*

So try something like this:

```
// this is your DataTable
DataTable custTable ;

// create a UniqueConstraint instance and set its columns that should make up
// that uniqueness constraint - in your case, that would be a set of *three*
// columns, obviously! Adapt to your needs!
UniqueConstraint custUnique = 
   new UniqueConstraint(new DataColumn[] { custTable.Columns["CustomerID"], 
                                           custTable.Columns["CompanyName"] });

// add unique constraint to the list of constraints for your DataTable
custTable.Constraints.Add(custUnique);
```

And that should do the trick for you!

Comment: What if I already have a populated DataTable and want to extract duplicate rows into another data table, all duplicates grouped together, along with their row numbers, based on a group of unique keys?

Answer (score 1):

To make your columns enforce a UNIQUE constraint you could use

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("UniqueColumn");
dt.Columns["UniqueColumn"].Unique = true;
```

**Solution two**

If you want some combination of the values in some columns to have unique value, you can try this.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("UniqueColumn1");
dt.Columns.Add("UniqueColumn2");
dt.Columns.Add("UniqueColumn3");
dt.Columns.Add("NormalColumn");

string 
       value1 = string.Empty, 
       value2 = string.Empty, 
       value3 = string.Empty, 
       value4 = string.Empty;

//Logic to take values in string values variables goes here

DataRow[] founded = dt.Select("UniqueColumn1 = '"+ value1+
                              "' and UniqueColumn2 = '"+value2+
                              "' and UniqueColumn3 = '"+value3+"'");
if (founded.Length > 0)
      // Message to say values already exist.
else
      // Add a new row to your dt.
```

In this code you check the data present in DT to enforce uniqueness

Comment: You mean combination of the values in 3 columns has to be unique, not the value in one column only ??

Comment: a value can be duplicated in the same column but the combination of values from 3 column for any row should be unique.

So definitely I cannot put Unique key on any single column.